# Templete engine vs ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about templting engines and ReactJs. First of i'm a beginner to web development and I don't know a lot but hopefully you will get the point. Can I use React and not any other templeting engine to render pages from the server?

any help would really be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is a javascript library for building UI (https://reactjs.org/).
And because it is in javascript, the pages will be rendered in client side.

You don't need a template engine when you work with React.